# Does Devise call reset_session in its SessionsController create and destroy methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I was reading the rubyonrails security doc (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) and I saw that it is best practice to `reset_session` when you `create` and `destroy` a session.

I was wondering if Devise's `SessionsController#create` and `SessionsController#destroy` already does this.

Comment: You can read the session controller code here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb, I couldn't find enough usage of `reset_session` in devise codebase.

Comment: Would it be necessary to override the method to reset sessions to prevent session fixation?

Comment: You can ask the same question in google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/plataformatec-devise. I trust `devise` would follow best practices.